# Having trouble connecting C# executable to database file on remote computer

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string, database-connection, remote-access

Using VC# I've created a staff management app that, upon its first run, is expected to query the user for the path to a (.mdf) database which will reside on a remote computer.  A resulting path may be something like

```
string dbPath = @"P:\remoteComputer\public\StaffTool\ExamplePersonnelDatabase.mdf";
```

Then I'm placing this string into a connection string template as so:

```
string dbConnectTemplate = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename={0};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
string dbConnectionString = String.Format(dbConnectionTemplate,dbPath);
```

Then I'm attempting to connect to the database LINQ to SQL style

```
ManagementDBDataContext db = new ManagementDBDataContext(
                dbConnectionString);
```

At this point, an error pop's up stating that

> The file "P:\remoteComputer\public\StaffTool\ExamplePersonnelDatabase.mdf" is on a network path that is not supported for database files.
>
> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file P:\remoteComputer\public\StaffTool\ExamplePersonnelDatabase.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

As I am relatively new to databases, I completely do not understand this message.  And obviously, the file is not on a UNC share.

Any ideas?

---

Jim Lamb recommended that I connect to an instance of SQL server running remotely.  Considering that I'm using LINQ to SQL, what refactoring do I have to do to make this happen?  Other ideas still welcome - especially "push this button and everything will work" solutions.

---

Another clue: A coworker said that there used to be some way to work through Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Data Sources(ODBC) so that a remote database could be viewed from my computer as if it was local.  The coworker didn't know any more details besides this.

Comment: Re "the file is not on a UNC share": it is if it "will reside on a remote computer"

Comment: But the P: is mapped to a network share (i.e. UNC path) correct?  If that's the case, SQL just recognizes that P:\ is a network share and is not allowed, see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304261

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to connect to a database file on another machine over a network connection, which isn't supported by SQL Express. You'll need to make a local copy and attach to that, or connect to an instance of SQL that's running on the same machine as the MDF file.

Comment: The second option there seem more attractive, but how much refactoring do I have to do to do with my code in order to connect to a remote instance of SQL?  Consider that I'm using LINQ to SQL.

Comment: You shouldn't need to modify your code at all - just your connection string. Then, of course, you'll need to install SQL Express on the remote machine, attach the MDF file, etc.